# After a jQuery load command is there a way to force a wait until the html has been rendered into the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have (basically) this code -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#loadDiv").load("mypage.html", function(){ alert($("#someText").text()) });
    });
</script>
<div id="loadDiv"></div>
```

However the alert will display "undefined" since the html has not been rendered into the div yet.

I've seen this question - [How to wait for jQuery's load function to render loaded content before executing callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085954/how-to-wait-for-jquerys-load-function-to-render-loaded-content-before-executing) - and Jake's answer is the best for my situation.  On my actual page I have eight of these and with a two second delay there are still some of them running before the html is rendered.

Does anyone have a better suggestion than increasing the delay to silly times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/), the `load` method already waits for the content to be placed in the element before calling the function:

> "If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed."

I have tested this, and it does find the loaded content in the element when the callback function runs.

If it doesn't work in your code, you are trying to do something other than what you have shown in the question.

Comment: You're right.  I was calling another function; I've lost what I was doing when I was originally getting the error but I think I was doing something like `$("#loadDiv").load("mypage.html", myFunction());` instead of `$("#loadDiv").load("mypage.html", function(){myFunction()});`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to wrap your code in the callback with a `setTimeout()` with a timeout of `0` (browsers are meant to clamp at `4` microseconds, but not all do).

This will push the code onto the event queue, giving the browser a chance to render before the code is executed.

Comment: I'd tried setTimeout with delays of 250+ and I kept getting errors (I was loading a function in my actual code) tried it again now and it's working prefectly.... Not sure what I was doing wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the html empty(if you don't have other html element in the div while the request is loading).
After the success (the complete event)you load the content (now I don't know if the response is an html or a text, i've done the example following your code).
You can also set a predefinite text if the request fail.

Check also this link for more information [jquery\load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), but this should be work

```
$("#loadDiv").load("mypage.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "success") {
    $("#loadDiv").html("");
  }
  else if(status == "complete"){
          $("#loadDiv").text();
   }
});
```